# Is that neccessary to create ModelView Everytime I run into Join Statement?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvvm, repository

Sorry if this is a newbie question.
But Recently I try to build a repository, for asp mvc application, and then I realize, that when I need to join some tables. I need to build an new ModelView. Again and Again for different view.

Is that neccessary to do this, everytime you run in join statement? or my design database is wrong?
thanks.

Comment: Joining two tables is normal, but when you have to get results based on column selection from multiple tables, you need to create a new Entity to store those results. If your results are limited to the scope of some method you can use the dynamic object. You can also return these dynamic objects to the caller.

Answer (score 1):

You can have one main model include every fields and sub models you want and every time you select different sub set of query, you using this main model. Example mine generic function :-

```
public  List<T> IncludeMultipleWithWhere(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes, Expression<Func<T, T>> select=null)
    {
        IQueryable<T> itemWithIncludes = dbContext.Set<T>() as IQueryable<T>;
        try
        {
            if (select != null)
            {
               itemWithIncludes = includes.Aggregate(itemWithIncludes,
                          (current, include) => current.Include(include)).Where(predicate).Select(select);
            }
            else
            {
                return dbContext.Set<T>().Where(predicate);
            }//end if-else

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Error("Error", ex);
        }
        finally { }
        return itemWithIncludes.ToList();
    }
```

Your calling function can pass in the main model as T , and different select expression. example:-

```
Expression<Func<CRM_RelationTbl, bool>> whereCond1 = (x) => x.intCRM == 0;
Expression<Func<CRM_RelationTbl, object>>[] includeMulti = { n => n.promotion.partners, n => n.program, n => n.campaign };
System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<CRM_RelationTbl,CRM_RelationTbl>> select = u => new CRM_RelationTbl
                                                                                                        {
                                                                                                            intCat = u.intCat,
                                                                                                            intCatRef=u.intCatRef,
                                                                                                            varCatRef = u.varCatRef,
                                                                                                             nvarDesc =u.nvarDesc 
                                                                                                        };

serviceRelation.IncludeMultipleWithWhere(whereCond1, includeMulti,select)
```

Comment: Uhh, sorry but I don't entirely understand your code. And where's the join part? Should I put this in generic repository?

Comment: The join is the include, like n => n.promotion.partners mean include sub table promotion and sub sub table partners.